# Are condition signals better performance-wise than semaphores in multi-release cases?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I currently have some (working) code implemented, doing a histogram through the usage of a semaphore.

Here's a rough pseudocode outline:

```
// init multi and one to 0, initial lock state

void* helper(void*)
{
sem_wait(multi); // wait for one to finish its work before starting
cnt++
...
cnt--;
if (cnt == 0) sem_post(one); // release one when the work is finished
}

compute_histogram(void*)
{
... initialize globals that multi will be using ...

for (all threads) {sem_post(multi)); // releases every waiting thread at multi

sem_wait(one); // forces one to wait to finish return until helper's work has finished
return;
}
```

Performance increases, compared to the single-threaded version, are there, about 6-8x, though I had a less threaded, less complicated version that was doing about the same; still, I can't help but think that I could be doing more. I'm extremely new to multi-threading (learned it this week) and looked at the man pages for pthread_cond, and I saw that the broadcast() command allows all threads to be released, which seems much quicker than the for loop on sem_post, as that must call into the OS every time in order to release exactly one thread.

My questions are:

Would broadcasting/condition codes be more suited to this case/substantially faster? I understand that semaphores include the features for waits and mutexes all in one and I could instead break it down into conds and muteness.

How would the initialization of such an implementation look? I believe I understand how the signal and wait commands work but I struggle to see their relation to the mutex reference that must be passed in, alongside any initialization of the cond variable itself? I would be interested in pseudocode and explanations of what it's doing.

Comment: For most _"is X better than Y"_ questions, the answer usually depends on numerous environmental conditions under which you will normally be operating. The best answer is the one which you can prove yourself through testing. Construct a series of rigorous experiments to emulate the kind of scenarios you need to handle. Then implement the approaches you want to compare against one another, and run your experiments on these to generate a set of performance results that can be compared directly.

Comment: I don't think a condition variable helps you here.  Normally it's associated with a single mutex, which means that the threads can only wake up one by one as they successively take the mutex.  And if you come up with some algorithm with N mutexes then the "one" thread (can we think of a better term for it btw?) has to loop over them, so you still have N system calls.

Comment: It seems to me that this is two separate problems to be solved separately.  One, awaken all the helpers after the main thread finishes its initialization.  (Maybe natural for a read-write lock?) Two, resume the main thread when all the helpers are done.  They don't both have to use the same approach, or the same semaphore/mutex/whatever.

Comment: I was thinking of just trapping the "multi" threads in some sort of infinite loop until the "one" thread completes the global variable updating, as a sort of self-made barrier, that I would then allow to continue using atomic operations. This is quite simply a multi-threading "bulk parallel" case through different functions. I'm surprised no barrier type mechanisms exist for the release of the threads in function1.

Comment: This seems to be related to [one of the OP's previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74567231/do-any-mechanisms-similar-to-pthread-barrier-exist-that-allow-thread-communica), where they explain that a pthreads program using semaphores to coordinate threads is consuming *several times* the runtime of the corresponding serial version.  As I commented there, such a performance issue is unlikely to be resolved just by choosing a different kind of synchronization object.