# Do any mechanisms, similar to pthread_barrier, exist that allow thread communication across functions?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to find out if there exists some sort of barrier-like mechanism to prevent threads in one function from proceeding until some condition has been met.

I attempted to implement this by the following:

```
function1 (multiple threads are here):
{...
while(suspended){} /* runs forever while suspended = 1, could also do while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&suspended, 1, 0)) {} */
...}
function2(one thread is here):
{...updates some resource the function1 threads need
suspended = 0; // takes out the suspended factor, could also do atomically
while(!donewithwork){} // will be released upon end of work of func1
return;
}
```

This implementation typically doesn't work and causes a full program crash. Looking in gdb wasn't too enlightening, the global variable "suspended" is decremented to 0, but in both cases, all threads are stuck in the while loops.

Online, I found that there exists a "pthreads_cond" section of functions devoted to this, but after talking to some people, I found that the multi-lock and release ends up having the same cost (in terms of system calls) as the following implementation:

```
// init multi and one to 0, initial lock state

void* helper(void*)
{
sem_wait(multi); // wait for one to finish its work before starting
cnt++
...
cnt--;
if (cnt == 0) sem_post(one); // release one when the work is finished
}

compute_histogram(void*)
{
... initialize globals that multi will be using ...

for (all threads) {sem_post(multi)); // releases every waiting thread at multi

sem_wait(one); // forces one to wait to finish return until helper's work has finished
return;
}
```

This has significant performance increases, 6-8x, over the single-threaded version, but the system calls required by the semaphore have significant overhead.

I'm wondering if there exists a type of "pthread_barrier" type mechanism that would release the threads upon a condition being met (by some other thread).

Comment: condition variable is what you want

Comment: That's what I thought, using pthread_cond_broadcast(). However, I'm confused by the issue of mutexes. I'm really struggling to understand why they are needed in the cond variable implementation and whether the number of unlocks will have to equal the n number of threads being released, thus costing the same as just doing my semaphore for loop.

Comment: Isn't this not the same question you asked yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554649/are-condition-signals-better-performance-wise-than-semaphores-in-multi-release-c

Comment: Yes. No one answered my question about the mutexes and condition codes. @Pablo

Comment: Worry about correct semantics first.  If the result is too slow, *then* worry about how to make it faster.

Comment: I'd like to understand why mutexes are needed in condition codes. If the condition code is the signal itself, why is the mutex needed?

Comment: Condition variables work together with mutexes.  They cannot be used without.  This is completely natural, because for a thread approaching a potential CV wait to determine whether the condition for waiting (whatever that is) is satisfied, it needs to consult one or more shared variables.  And it needs to synchronize to do that, which purpose is served by a mutex.  In practice, one very often needs mutual exclusion in the vicinity of a CV wait more generally than that, too.

Comment: Or to put it another way, a CV provides a means for threads to suspend their operation and to be notified to resume, but proper use is always associated with waiting for some *condition* to be satisfied by the program's state in order for threads to continue past the point of a CV wait.  Semantically, a CV *does not* indicate whether or not to proceed.  It's the associated predicate that does that.  The CV's job is to help threads coordinate setting and especially *checking* the predicate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @JohnBollinger , how is this different from a semaphore? From my understanding, a semaphore serves the same purpose. I was wondering if condition codes do so in a less costly manner.

Comment: @cspurposesonly, I anticipate that a correct CV-based solution to your problem could perform better than a semaphore based one on account of the fact that only one system call is needed to release all the waiting threads.  The total number of system calls is probably not very different, but the CV approach distributes them more evenly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I attempted to implement it with CVs but I was struggling with understanding the place of the mutex. In my implementation, no mutex is needed. All I need to do is signal that the threads can move on.

Comment: HOWEVER, if you're seeing such a massive performance loss from your semaphore-based approach as you describe in the question then you're focusing on the wrong problem.  That the overhead from threading and synchronization so dominates the run time of your program tells me that the work assigned to your threads is too fine grained.  You need your threads to each do much more work between synchronizations than they now do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not anymore, but in the place of a semaphore, I used a volatile int while suspending threads with a while(! we've deactivated the volatile int barrier) and it worked fine. In the end, I'm going with my less-threaded version as the performance was similar, though I'm kind of disappointed.